# C++ :: Set value function sets inside function but followed by Get function the set value is gone

Tags: c++, debugging, stdvector

Hopefully I am missing something super obvious with this:

Trying to set a value of an asset (class) with an asset property modifier (class) using some vectors as containers. This seems to work during the function call, but when following the set call with a get call to confirm, it is as if the set call did not happen. See code and output below:

The asset.h file:

```
namespace assets {
class Asset 
{
  friend class AssetPropertyModifier;
  std::vector<properties::AssetPropertyDouble> asset_property_double_;
  enum property_id_ { ZERO, USHORT, FLOAT, INT, UINT, DOUBLE, VEC3, STRING, 
       BOOL};
public:
  void AddProperty(std::string property_name, double property_value);
};//class Asset
}//namespace assets
```

AddProperty is working just fine so I am omitting that and the .cpp as not relevant. Just does a push_back into the vector to add the value, along with some indexing tracking.

In the asset property header:

```
namepsace properties {
struct AssetPropertyDouble
{
private:
  friend class AssetPropertyModifier;
  double real_number_value_;
public:
  AssetPropertyDouble(double d) : real_number_value_(d) {}
};//struct AssetPropertyDouble
}//namespace proeprties
```

Here is the APM header:

```
namespace assets {
class Asset;
class AssetPropertyModifier
{
  int LookUpVectorIndex(Asset a, int type , int index);
  int LookUpNameIndex(Asset a, std::string s);
public:
  double GetPropertyValue(Asset a, std::string property_name, 
         double not_used_just_an_overloader);
  void SetPropertyValue(Asset a, std::string property_name, 
       double new_double_value);
};//class AssetPropertyModifier
}//namespace assets
```

In the APM .cpp file:

```
namespace assets {

//LookUpNameIndex definition
//LookUpVectorIndex defintion

double AssetPropertyModifier::GetPropertyValue(Asset a, 
                              std::string property_name, 
                              double not_used_just_an_overloader)
{
  //Using Verbose output to debug:
  std::cout << "------------GET-------------------" << std::endl;
  int name_index = LookUpNameIndex(a, property_name);
  std::cout << "names vector index is " << name_index << std::endl;
  int double_index = LookUpVectorIndex(a, a.DOUBLE, name_index);
  std::cout << "double property vector index is " << double_index << 
       std::endl;
  double property_value = 
       a.asset_property_double_.at(double_index).real_number_value_;
  std::cout << property_name << " are equal to " << property_value << 
       std::endl;
  return property_value;
}

void AssetPropertyModifier::SetPropertyValue(Asset a, 
                            std::string property_name, 
                            double new_double_value)
{
   //Using Verbose output to debug:
  std::cout << "------------SET-------------------" << std::endl;
  int name_index = LookUpNameIndex(a, property_name);
  std::cout << "names vector index is " << name_index << std::endl;
  int double_index = LookUpVectorIndex(a, a.DOUBLE, name_index);
  std::cout << "double vector index is " << double_index << std::endl;
  a.asset_property_double_.at(double_index).real_number_value_ = 
       new_double_value;
  std::cout << property_name << " was changed to " <<
        a.asset_property_double_.at(double_index).real_number_value_
        << std::endl;
}//SetPropertyValue

}//namespace assets
```

Then when I use this prototype, I get the following to happen:

from main.cpp example:

```
std::string some_name = "Property Name";
double some_initial_value = 5.5;
double some_new_value = 4.4;
assets::AssetPropertyModifier apm;
assets::Asset my_asset;

main {
  my_asset.AddProperty(some_name, some_initial_value);
  std::cout << "Current value = " << apm.GetPropertyValue(my_asset, 
       some_name , _DOUBLE_)
       << std::endl;

  apm.SetPropertyValue(my_asset, some_name , some_new_value );

  std::cout << "Current value = " << apm.GetPropertyValue(my_asset, 
       some_name , _DOUBLE_)
       << std::endl;
}
```

This is the resulting output:

```
------------GET-------------------
names vector index is 0
double property vector index is 0
Property Name are equal to 5.5
Current value = 5.5
------------SET-------------------
names vector index is 0
double vector index is 0
Property Name was changed to 4.4
------------GET-------------------
names vector index is 0
double property vector index is 0
Property Name are equal to 5.5
Current value = 5.5
```

As you can see above the GET returned 5.5 and the SET Claims it updated to 4.4 but then the following GET shows 5.5 still.

One other thing I can provide to help troubleshoot this is that if I set the property to be public so that I can access the Asset properties directly from main for sake of testing, it updates correctly:

```
//hard SET with public access to the vector and the property struct value
my_asset.asset_property_double_.at(0).real_number_value_ = 3.3;
//hard GET with public access:
std::cout << my_asset.asset_property_double_.at(0).real_number_value_ << 
     std::endl;
//GET through APM but with public values still enabled:
std::cout << "Current value = " << apm.GetPropertyValue(my_asset, some_name, 
     _DOUBLE_)
    << std::endl;
```

That output is:

```
3.3
------------GET-------------------
names vector index is 0
double property vector index is 0
Property Name are equal to 3.3
Current value = 3.3
```

Does anyone know why the SET function is not sticking above? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Maybe I misread it, but it looks like you are passing in a copy of your asset rather than the actual asset when you are setting the new value. Have you tried passing by reference?

Comment: @EastonBornemeier  -  Yes that is exactly right.  Thank you much for catching it for me. Looking at it too long and knew I missed something obvious. Appreciate your time.

Comment: No problem! I added it as an answer. If you could mark it correct I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Done. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a copy of your asset rather than the reference to the asset, so you are actually only updating the copy, not the actual. You will need to pass by reference instead:

```
void AssetPropertyModifier::SetPropertyValue(Asset& a,        //<----added '&'
                            std::string property_name, 
                            double new_double_value)
{
   //Using Verbose output to debug:
  std::cout << "------------SET-------------------" << std::endl;
  int name_index = LookUpNameIndex(a, property_name);
  std::cout << "names vector index is " << name_index << std::endl;
  int double_index = LookUpVectorIndex(a, a.DOUBLE, name_index);
  std::cout << "double vector index is " << double_index << std::endl;
  a.asset_property_double_.at(double_index).real_number_value_ = 
       new_double_value;
  std::cout << property_name << " was changed to " <<
        a.asset_property_double_.at(double_index).real_number_value_
        << std::endl;
}//SetPropertyValue
```